# Get Device Registration Token iPhone before registering

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to get the device token (the one that is set in `DidRegisterForRemoteNotifications`) of an iPhone Device before you call `registerForRemoteNotifications`? If so, how can you do this?

I want to get this token and send it to my server. I may need to get this token before the push notification actually happens, in case the person doesn't allow push notifications at that time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get the token before you request it. That is the purpose of the registration process.

You can't send push notifications until the user has allowed your application to receive them.  The user may also withdraw permission for your application to show notifications at any time.

Comment: I see, and if the user withdraws permission, does the token change?

Comment: No, the token will remain the same. You can even still send notifications, but they won't be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Calling `-registerForRemoteNotifications` is **how** you get the device token in the first place; .  In fact, `-application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called in response to invoking `-registerForRemoteNotifications`.  You generally do this inside of your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and no notifications will be delivered to the device until it has registered.

For reference, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2.

> 1. Register your app’s supported interaction types as described in [Registering Your iOS App's Supported User Interaction Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW25).
> 2. Call the [registerForRemoteNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotifications) method to register your app for remote notifications. (In OS X, you use the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method to register your app’s interaction types and register for remote notifications in one step.)
> 3. Use your app delegate’s [application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:) method to receive the device token needed to deliver remote notifications. Use the [application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:) method to process errors.
> 4. If registration was successful, send the device token to the server you use to generate remote notifications.